# calling compute on a dask.dataframe converts datetime64[ns] to object

Tags: pandas, dask-dataframe

I've attemped a MCVE below but it works. However, my parquet file is created in databricks and I am now reading it in locally so not sure if that is part of the issue. Therefore, open to suggestions of things to try. Works with calls using `to_datetime`.

Here's a screenshot of my 'real-world' problem:

[image]

and code here:

```
print(df.DATE.dtype)
print(df.compute().DATE.dtype)
print(dd.to_datetime(df.DATE).compute().dtype)
print(pd.to_datetime(df.compute().DATE).dtype)
```

MCVE (but works):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': pd.date_range('2000', freq='D', periods=3)})
>>> df.col1.dtype
dtype('<M8[ns]')

import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, 1)
>>> ddf.col1.dtype
dtype('<M8[ns]')
>>> ddf.compute().col1.dtype
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Comment: What's the problem here? The text code seems okay. I think you need to check your jupyter notebook for execution order.

Comment: @Vishnudev updated picture

Comment: Are you doing something before calling compute? If yes, then that could be a problem and you should add that to your post.